# Python program not going back to first player after second player

Tags: python

I am trying to create a battleship board game using python and tkinter and it works well except i am not able to go back to the first frame after finishing the second players turn. The code runs simpl off of two functions and works fine as each function is run individually. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()


ship_sizes =[5,4,3,2,2]
board_size = 10

board1 = []
board2 = []
for i in range(board_size):
    row =[]
    for j in range(board_size):
        row.append(0)
    board1.append(row)
    
for i in range(board_size):
    row =[]
    for j in range(board_size):
        row.append(0)
    board2.append(row)
    
for ship in ship_sizes:
   while True:
        x = random.randint(0,board_size-1)
        y= random.randint(0,board_size-1)
        orien = random.choice(['hor','vert'])
        if orien == 'hor' and x + ship <= board_size:
            valid = True
            for i in range(ship):
                if board1[x+i][y] != 0:
                    valid = False
                    break
            if valid:
                for i in range(ship):
                    board1[x+i][y]=ship
                break
        elif orien == 'vert' and y + ship <= board_size:
            valid = True
            for i in range(ship):
                if board1[x][y+i] != 0:
                    valid=False
                    break
            if valid:
                for i in range(ship):
                    board1[x][y+i]=ship
                break
            
            
for ship in ship_sizes:
   while True:
        x = random.randint(0,board_size-1)
        y= random.randint(0,board_size-1)
        orien = random.choice(['hor','vert'])
        if orien == 'hor' and x + ship <= board_size:
            valid = True
            for i in range(ship):
                if board2[x+i][y] != 0:
                    valid = False
                    break
            if valid:
                for i in range(ship):
                    board2[x+i][y]=ship
                break
        elif orien == 'vert' and y + ship <= board_size:
            valid = True
            for i in range(ship):
                if board2[x][y+i] != 0:
                    valid=False
                    break
            if valid:
                for i in range(ship):
                    board2[x][y+i]=ship
                break
def button_click1(x,y):
    if board1[x][y] == 0:
        button = buttons1[x][y]
        button.config(text="Miss",bg = "white")
        buttons1[x][y].config(text="Miss",bg = "white")
    elif board1[x][y] == 1:
        button = buttons1[x][y]
        button.config(text="Hit",bg="darkkhaki")
        buttons1[x][y].config(text="Miss",bg = "white")
    else:
        button = buttons1[x][y]
        button.config(text = "Hit", bg="darkkhaki")
        buttons1[x][y].config(text="Miss",bg = "white")
        
def button_click2(x,y):
    if board2[x][y] == 0:
        button = buttons2[x][y]
        button.config(text="Miss",bg = "white")
        buttons2[x][y].config(text="Miss",bg = "white")
    elif board2[x][y] == 1:
        button = buttons2[x][y]
        button.config(text="Hit",bg="darkkhaki")
        buttons2[x][y].config(text="Miss",bg = "white")
    else:
        button = buttons2[x][y]
        button.config(text = "Hit", bg="darkkhaki")
        buttons2[x][y].config(text="Miss",bg = "white")
    
buttons1=[]
buttons2=[]

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(board_size):
        row = []
        for k in range(board_size):
            button = tk.Button(master=window,text="",bg="deepskyblue",width=2,height=1,command=lambda x=j,y=k:button_click1(x,y))
            row.append(button)
        buttons1.append(row)
        
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(board_size):
        row = []
        for k in range(board_size):
            button = tk.Button(master=window,text="",bg="deepskyblue",width=2,height=1,command=lambda x=j,y=k:button_click2(x,y))
            row.append(button)
        buttons2.append(row)
def frame1():
    
    for i in range(board_size):
        for j in range(board_size):
            buttons1[i][j].grid(row=i,column=j)

    next =tk.Button(master=window, text="next",bg="green", width=5,height=2,command=frame2)
    next.grid(row=11,column=11)

def frame2():
    for i in range(board_size):
        for j in range(board_size):
            buttons2[i][j].grid(row=i,column=j)
   
    
    next =tk.Button(master=window, text="next",bg="green", width=5,height=2,command=frame1)
    next.grid(row=11,column=11)


frame1()
    
window.mainloop()
```

The first player goes and it works, the second player goes and it works, but after that it doesn't go back to the first player

Comment: You're just layering player 2's Buttons on top of player 1's, in the same grid cells.  When you try to display player 1 again, calling `.grid()` on their Buttons does nothing, because they were already on the grid (just covered up).  You need to call `.grid_forget()` on the other player's Buttons to hide them.

Comment: now it send back to player 1 but won't send to player 2